# DirectX 10 - determining if hardware device is available

Tags: c#, slimdx, directx10

I am writing an offline renderer using SlimDX and Direct3D 10 that will need to be run on machines without graphics cards (servers). On these machines, I'll be using the WARP software renderer.

Is it possible to tell if a hardware device is present without throwing an exception in SlimDX? Currently I'm having to do this:

```
            try
            {
                Device device = new Device1(DriverType.Hardware, deviceCreationFlags,
                    FeatureLevel.Level_10_1);

                return device;
            }
            catch (Direct3D10Exception)
            {
                return null;
            }
```

And then create a WARP device if null is returned.

However, each time the exception is thrown, it breaks Visual Studio, which is annoying, and it doesn't seem like I should be catching an exception to determine if a feature is available.

Any way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general you can use `SlimDX.Configuration.ThrowOnError` to almost-globally enable or disable exceptions. You can also set up more complex exception exclusions via `SlimDX.Configuration.AddResultWatch`.

You cannot, however, prevent SlimDX from throwing exceptions of a constructor (by design). This is because that's the only way to signal failure of a construction aside from constructing an object in a zombie state (which is ugly). The static method `Device.CreateWithSwapChain` should be usable for constructing your device without throwing (if you disable exceptions). If this doesn't work, please file a bug on the SlimDX issue tracker.

You are correct that it's generally preferable to avoid relying on exceptions for flow control (that is, it's better to be able to ask if something will fail than to have to try it and wait for it to fail, although this is not always possible). SlimDX should support this and if not, it's a bug.

As an aside, you probably have "break on throw" enabled in Visual Studio via the Debug -> Exceptions menu. You can configure how VS reacts to exceptions from that window -- unchecking everything will prevent the debugger from triggering a breakpoint when an exception is raised.

Comment: Thanks Josh. Unfortunately Device.CreateWithSwapChain won't work for me - I need a customized swap chain. I know about "break on throw", thanks ;) I switch this off most of the time to avoid this exception, but that means I occasionally miss something. I'd rather know when exceptions happen.

Comment: You can configure them on a specific type-by-type basis, although that will still squelch (or not) all D3D10 exceptions. Sounds like we need to provide you with a static CreateDevice() wrapper (or expose whatever the native free function is for testing device capabilities in 10). Probably your best bet will be to [file a bug](http://code.google.com/p/slimdx/issues/list). We'll try to get it fixed ASAP.

Comment: Looking at the documentation, it seems something is already available to do the same in D3D11 - you can query feature levels before creating the device. I guess I need something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Why not? Exceptions are how you signal error conditions in objects. If a constructor fails, throwing an exception is the only way to signal that failure.

You ask the `Device` constructor to create a D3D10 device. If no such device exists, what should it do? Create a broken `Device` object that you can't use, which you have to check to see if it is a working? That's basically assuming that your users will properly code the proper fallbacks into their applications. That's a recipe for disaster; it's much better to use an exception to *force* the user to code fallbacks, rather than hope that they'll do the right thing.

As for "breaking Visual Studio", I have never seen VS "break" under throwing an exception. What kind of breakage are you experiencing? VS will only halt if the exception goes uncaught. Maybe you're not catching the right type of exception?

Comment: Note that this code is C#, so the comment regarding catching exceptions by reference doesn't apply (exceptions are reference types).

Comment: I'd like to test if creating such a device is possible *before* trying to create the device. It will be a common occurance, and not exceptional at all.

Comment: And by 'breaking visual studio' I mean the exception causes visual studio to enter debug mode, as if a breakpoint had been set. I believe this term is commonly used, see System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break().

Comment: An exception in a constructor? Why in the world would you ever need to have an exception in a constructor anyway? AFAIK it's a poor programming practice to throw exceptions in constructors and should never be done unless particularly necessary, which I don't think it would be the case of a DX wrapper such as SlimDX.

Comment: @Pablo: That's _standard_ programming practice. The only way to signal a failed object construction is to throw an exception in a constructor. And while there are many programmers who take efforts to avoid them (which are bad for the reasons I explained), it is the only mechanism that _forces_ the user to deal with the error. It forces you to write correct code. And in a good API, it should be impossible to write bad code. A throwing constructor prevents ignoring the error.

Comment: It's solved by reading the docs about the function. Of course nowadays people don't like to learn how to use it, they just want to use it. Or they don't want to write a doc about it? Besides I'm talking about using exceptions in a constructor, but by using an "init()" that throws an exception you enforce the error and still... well if they don't know that they must call init() before anything else, they didn't read the docs how would they ever code anything anyway :S.

Comment: @Pablo: C#, C++, Java, and many other OOP languages defines the function that gets called "before anything else". It's called _the constructor_. You are syntactically forbidden from using an object without calling the constructor (except in C++, where you can end-run around it, but that's malicious and undefined). I don't know about you, but I would much rather have an API that _cannot_ be used incorrectly than one that can. A good API makes it easy to do things right and impossible, or exceedingly difficult, to do things wrong.

Comment: A constructor should be just to initialize some pointers that are required to be null. Initialize an object with parameters is ok for something small such a string or something like that but if you are interfacing with an api and initializing a whole virtual thing in a constructor then that's very wrong.

Comment: @Nicol but why would you ever create a device if you don't have in the first place? I don't even load the whole d3d thing if I don't have it :S it would be closer to calling ResetDevice() than checking if there is any d3d in the system

Comment: Sorry probably I should stick to my area even if I did high-level oop before, now I can't understand it anymore :S perhaps in some specific scripting context I would agree. I get used to interfaces and some things I believe that people in c# don't even need to know about, where you have control about objects being created, pure virtual, etc.